# Уникальное значение из двух ID

Tags: логика, криптография, хеширование, php

Есть уникальные id двух юзеров. Нужно создать общее место встречи юзеров, обозвав это место уникальным именем, так чтобы по id одного и второго юзера можно было определить в каких местах он был.
Думаю сделать арифметическую операцию между двумя ID и зашифровать. Что скажете вы, с учетом быстродействия и простоты?

Comment: А для чего шифровать то? если вы это собираетесь хранить в БД то логично просто сделать связку на юзверей. Мне кажется что вы что-то мудрите.

Comment: > Думаю сделать арифметическую операцию между двумя ID

какая каша...

Comment: как сделать связку?

Comment: google -> связь многие ко многим, если вкратце - создается промежуточная таблица, каждая из записей представляет собой эту связь и содержит два (или более, если у нас связь из более чем двух сущностей) айдишника необходимых юзеров.

Comment: Я знаю что такое связь многие ко многим - комментарий ниже к ответу..

Comment: Может ключ создать просто вида ID1_ID2, т-е 145_1, 145_2?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно. Не чётко сформулирован вопрос. НО.
Если ID пользователей уникально ДЛЯ КАЖДОГО а местра хранятся в виде отдельной табличной структуры (одно уровневой/много уровневой) то можно организовать связь многие ко многим (по сути место встречи). Если нужно организовать связь кто с кем и где, то помимо связи многие ко многим нужно создать таблицу с хранением идентификаторов связи и всё.

Comment: Проблема в том, что используется нереляционная БД - поэтому об очевидных связей многие ко многим - сложно говорить. Что можете предложить для такого случая?

Comment: @IOleg, с этого стоило начинать. Но в чем проблема создавать записи типа {user1:%id, user2:%id, smthother:%tralala}?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю - в вашем случае ключом что является? Для каждого сообщения создается свой ключ?

Comment: Думаю, использовать sorted set в таком формате: ZADD message.145_1 timestamp JSON Object, ключ будет message.145_1 из составных ID. далее ключ сортировки - время и значение JSON. Что скажете хранить в качестве ключа сортировки? и получается неудобно извлекать данные для 1_145, придется инвертировать ключ

Comment: все таки не удобно с ключом 1_145, потому как для юзера для второго юзера нужно будет создать ключ 145_1 и дублировать все переписку и туда. поэтому изначально хотел сделать hash двух чисел, чтобы вне зависимости от id переписку можно было извлекать с двух сторон для id = 1 и id =145

Answer (score 0):

Все таки нашел решение.
Я решил остановиться на концепции меньшее число первым. Т-е на входе в функцию у меня два уникальных числа, они сравниваются и меньшее записывается первым, затем через тире, второе. в итоге. 1_145. это и будет уникальный ключ для пользователей с id = 1 и id = 145. Даже если на входе будет 145,1 или 1,145 все равно ключ преобразуется к 1_145

---

Буду рад другому решению или пересмотру архитектуры нереляционной базы когда нужно создать комнану общения и внести в нее id пользователей - участников

Answer (score 0):

в реляционной субд ваша задача решается так (таблица: поля, указаны только ключевые)

```
user: user_id - первичный ключ: user_id
appointments: appointment_id, appointment_name - первичный ключ: appointment_id
user_appointment: appointment_id, user_id - в этой таблице столько строк сколько чел. участвуют в встрече. первичный ключ пара полей: appointment_id, user_id
```

даже если у вас не реляционная субд, подход к решению задачи тот-же

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такое свойство простых чисел: при их перемножении получается уникальное число, однозначно определяющее, что на что мы умножали. Допустим, у Вас 500 пользователей и Вам нужен идентификатор для места встречи 499-го и 500-го. Смотрим в Википедию: 499-ое простое число равно 3559, 500-ое - 3571. Их произведение равно 12709189. Для записи этого числа достаточно 24 бит. При желании можно составить программу, которая покажет, какое максимальное количество пользователей у нас может быть, чтобы уложиться в 32 или 64 бита.

Comment: Сервер, смотрящий в википедию - это будет шикарно.  
Можно еще диффи-хеллмана прикрутить, зачем - не знаю.  
Я кстати писал программу, раскладывающую 64битное число на два простых (тот самый диффи-хеллман) - 500 мс на эмуляторе смартфона. И это при том, что они считались от корня числа, т.к. должны были быть приблизительно одного порядка. Печка в общем будет, а не сервер)

Comment: "Сервер, смотрящий в википедию - это будет шикарно."

Надеюсь, это была шутка. Если да, то не смешно. А вот если нет, то это, как ни парадоксально, очень смешно. На башорг запостить, что ли?